# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.softworld.crib.models.User

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and am trying to implement the realtime database on android. I can write to the db succesfully but when i try to read from the db, I get `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.softworld.crib.models.User`

[image: Here is my DB on firebase]

This is how I post and read from the DB

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("myUsers");
String userId = dbRef.push().getKey();

        User user = new User("My New Name","mynewemail@gmail.com",loggedInUser.getPersonPhoto());
//how I post to db
        dbRef.child(userId).setValue(user);
//how I read from db
dbRef.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                List users = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = noteDataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, user.getPersonEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    users.add(user);
                }

                //Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                //Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```

And my User class looks like this

```
public class User {
    String personName,personEmail;
    Uri personPhoto;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String personName, String personEmail, Uri personPhoto) {
        this.personName = personName;
        this.personEmail = personEmail;
        this.personPhoto = personPhoto;
    }

    public String getPersonName() {
        return personName;
    }

    public void setPersonName(String personName) {
        this.personName = personName;
    }

    public String getPersonEmail() {
        return personEmail;
    }

    public void setPersonEmail(String personEmail) {
        this.personEmail = personEmail;
    }

    public Uri getPersonPhoto() {
        return personPhoto;
    }

    public void setPersonPhoto(Uri personPhoto) {
        this.personPhoto = personPhoto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change

```
  dbRef.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

to

```
  dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

as explained in https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Alternatively, if you really want to only get an event for this particular `userId`, the DataSnapshot your getting is probably already the  user you're looking for, so using `.getChildren()` in

```
  for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
```

is probably unnecessary.

Comment: i have changed that and the conversion error has dissapeared. however, am now getting java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class android.net.Uri

Comment: If it's not at the same place, it's another problem. Maybe you should document on how to debug an application (step-by-step, logs, read stacktraces....)

Comment: correct @Orabîg I found the problem was somewhere else. But your solution on changing to dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { solved my problem.